# Storyboard output not matching the simulation

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

Here is my desired output.
[image: Here is my desired output.]

I've made sure that each view in my scroll view has been constrained and pinned equally to each side, as seen here.
[image: as seen here.]

However, when I run the simulation, the views are slightly off to the left.
[image: the views are slightly off to the left.] Why is this happening?

EDIT: I listened to what you guys said and [got rid of the defined widths and heights](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4sYp.png), but [now I'm getting another error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QaCfG.png)

Comment: why are you specifying the width, if you have given left and right constraints?

Comment: You've said the width is 359. What did you expect to happen on a larger screen?

Comment: You should not add constraint for width property. Add left and right anchor constraint only.

Comment: As others have said it is almost certainly because you are specifying a fixed width in addition to constraints for leading and trailing.  You should find that there are messages about constraints breaking if you run it in the debugger.

Comment: To everyone that told me to get rid of the constraints. I did what you said and tried pinning it and now I'm getting errors.

Answer (score 2):

In that case, a recommend you to put everything stacked in a StackView.

you can do it selecting your views and after that click on that "embed in" icon, and select StackView
[image]

It will make easier to use manage left, right, top and bottom constraints.

After you click that probably all your views will get really close. And you will need to set spacing in the sidebar proprieties.

[image]

After that select your stacked view and add constraints to Landing, trailing, top, and bottom.

[image]

it will appear a red alert on your storyboard because you have not set the view's constraints relative to the stackedView, to do that, select all your views and click on Add Missing constraints at Select Views menu

[image]

don't forget to add Equal width and Equal height constraints

[image]

after you do everything your views will be the same for every iPhone

[image]